# Does the speed of capturing an objective depend on the number of people capturing?

Tags: overwatch

When your team is capturing an objective, does the speed of the capture depend on how many team members are actually capturing it?

I'm not talking about payloads, I'm asking specifically about those square objective areas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes it does.**
Source: Personal experience. However the speed is capped with 3 people as suggest [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ojae3/how_many_people_speed_up_the_capture_speed_of_an/). You can see that the speed does not increase or drop when going from 4 to 5 and back to 4 ppl.

Source: